# Connection to localhost failed - ActiveMQ in MacOs

Tags: java, macos, activemq-classic

I started a project in java with ActiveMQ 5.17.0.
Therefore I have downloaded ActiveMQ and opened my terminal from the folder bin and execute `./activemq start`.

I received:

```
INFO: Loading '/Users/NAME/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.17.0//bin/env'
INFO: Using java '/usr/bin/java'
INFO: Starting - inspect logfiles specified in logging.properties and log4j.properties to get details
./activemq: line 343: [: : integer expression expected
INFO: pidfile created : '/Users/NAME/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.17.0//data/activemq.pid' (pid '3084')
```

As I have seen in other posts, this is the expected result.

A part of my Java Code is:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:8161"); // ActiveMQ-specific
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        con = factory.createConnection();
        Session session = con.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE); // non-transacted session

        Queue queue = session.createQueue("test.queue"); // only specifies queue name

        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
        Message msg = session.createTextMessage("hello queue"); // text message
        producer.send(msg);

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close(); // free all resources
            } catch (JMSException e) { /* Ignore */ }
        }
    }
}
```

As soon as I try to open the website `https://localhost:8161/admin/admin` I receive the response that Safari, Chrome, and Firefox do not get connection to `localhost`.

Anybody any suggestions what to do?

I have already tried to download again, different browsers, start and stop the server several times.

Comment: I use 5.17.0, the latest version

Answer (score 0):

1. The URL for the admin UI should be `http`: `http://localhost:8161/admin` or `http://127.0.0.1:8161/admin/`
2. The script `activemq` fails parsing the output of `java -version`. Maybe set the line `VERSION=` to your java version (e.g. `VERSION=17` for java 17) to check if that is the issue.

Comment: how do I do step 2?

Comment: You should be able to edit the file "activemq" with a text editor and replace the line "VERSION=`"${JAVACMD}" -version 2>&1....." with VERSION=17

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample shows that you are attempting to send messages to the Web UI URL vs the JMS protocol port.

Try changing your code to use port '61616':

```
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616); // ActiveMQ-specific
```

For the web browser access, try starting with the non-SSL url: [http://localhost:8161/admin/admin](https://localhost:8161/admin/admin) instead of 'https'.